# Transforming a nonlinear homeomorphism by linear contraction on one term; still a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, nonlinear-analysis

I have a continuous nonlinear operator $f:X\rightarrow X$ with $X$ an infinite dimensional Banach space.
$\lambda I - f$ is a homeomorphism for all $|\lambda|\geq 1$.  I also have a linear operator $B$ with norm $||B||<1$, and I know that $\lambda I - Bf$ is proper for all $|\lambda|\geq 1$.

I would like to know if $I - Bf$ is necessarily a homeomorphism.  I am unable show it; $f$ has the troublesome property of being differentiable everywhere except at the origin, so I cannot use results about diffeomorphisms or the Neuberger spectrum.

Thanks!